# Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'. When debugging with Docker and VSCode

Tags: python, django, docker, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm setting up a debugger using docker-compose following [this guide](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-debugging-vs-code/). I've modified the file `manage.py` to run `debugpy` when `setting.DEBUG` exists but when reading the settings file it throws an exception of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`.

Here are the files I'm using:

`.env.dev`

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=foo
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0[::1]
```

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'zapping.settings')

    # start new section
    from django.conf import settings

    if settings.DEBUG:
        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') or os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'):
            import debugpy
            debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
            print('Attached!')
    # end new section


    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share full stack trace?

Comment: Please share the code where exactly you are getting an error.
And please share the full log of error.

Comment: @Tugay I've added the exact error

Comment: @Rodragon the problem is that you don't have `DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS` as environment variable

Comment: @Tugay I'm confused. I do have a `.env.dev` file with the `DJANGO_ALLOWD_HOSTS`...